# Does iPhone play music on the HomePod via WiFi or Bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, wifi, bluetooth, continuity, homepod

I’m wondering if asking the HomePod directly to play a stream produces better sound than the same stream in an app on the iPhone playing through near-field handoff to that HomePod?

Bluetooth would be a constraining factor in limiting the sound quality.

Comment: A quick visit to Wikipedia will show you that AirPlay uses the best available network to talk to other airplay devices. It will even create an ad-hoc network if one is not available. So if Wifi is available it uses WiFi, if it isn't it will (presumably) use other methods to connect to an AirPlay device, *not just Bluetooth* unless that is all it can use.

Comment: @SteveChambers If your Comment were an Answer, I’d mark it accepted.

Comment: It is a bit more complex if playing from AppleMusic - in that case the HomePod sometimes directly streams from Apple and not via the iPhone.

Comment: Done! thx, and HNY! & @mmmmmm I did not know that, but in retrospect, makes sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick visit to Wikipedia ([HomePod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HomePod) and [AirPlay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPlay)) will show you that AirPlay uses the best available network to talk to other airplay devices.

It will even create an ad-hoc network if one is not available.

So if Wifi is available it uses WiFi, if it isn't it will (presumably) use other methods to connect to an AirPlay device, not just Bluetooth unless that is all it can use.

Comment: [HomePod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HomePod) and [Airplay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPlay)